# How to assign a filename to a direct .mp3 download?

Tags: html, hyperlink, download, attributes, filenames

First of all, let me state that I have pretty much 0 knowledge of code. I own http://www.CultureLeak.com and I'm changing the way people can download off the site.

I have direct .mp3 links (f.e. http://dopefile.pk/mp3embed-74bktdjz1web.mp3)
and when you click them they always save as audio.mp3 (audio1.mp3, audio2mp3 etc). I want to assign them a filename. I tried doing this via html5 download attribute.

I can't get it to work (and it's not browser related). Any ideas/is it even possible to give a link like this an assigned name?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `download`attribute to name the file (not only for download) (click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp))

```
<a href="audio/yourAudio.mp3" download="yourAudioName.mp3">Download</a>
```